# Can these functions be generalized further?

Tags: scala

Below code uses case statement to determine which distance function should be applied manhattanDistance or eucleudianDistance
Can this code be generalized further using traits or DRY principle so it is more maintainable ?

```
object general {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet
  object DistanceOptions extends Enumeration {
     type Dist = Value
     val Manhattan, Eucleudian = Value
  }

  object DistanceFunctions {

    def manhattanDistance(l1: (DataLine, DataLine)): Double = {

      val t: List[(Double, Double)] = l1._1.points.zip(l1._2.points)
      t.map(m => Math.abs(m._1 - m._2)).sum

    }

    def eucleudianDistance(l1: (DataLine, DataLine)): Double = {

      val ld: List[(Double, Double)] = l1._1.points.zip(l1._2.points)
      val sum = ld.map(m => Math.abs(m._1 - m._2) + Math.abs(m._1 - m._2)).sum

      Math.sqrt(sum)
    }

    def getDistance(s: DistanceOptions.Dist, l1: (DataLine, DataLine)) = {

      s match {
        case DistanceOptions.Manhattan  => DistanceFunctions.manhattanDistance(l1)
        case DistanceOptions.Eucleudian => DistanceFunctions.eucleudianDistance(l1)
      }

      DistanceFunctions.manhattanDistance(l1)
      DistanceFunctions.eucleudianDistance(l1)
    }

  }

  case class DataLine(label: String, points: List[Double])
  val l = (DataLine("a", List(1, 2)), DataLine("b", List(1, 2)))
                                                  //> l  : (general.DataLine, general.DataLine) = (DataLine(a,List(1.0, 2.0)),Dat
                                                  //| aLine(b,List(1.0, 2.0)))
  DistanceFunctions.getDistance(DistanceOptions.Manhattan, l)
                                                  //> res0: Double = 0.0
  DistanceFunctions.getDistance(DistanceOptions.Eucleudian, l)


                                                     //> res1: Double = 0.0
}
```

Updated using type classes :

```
object gen extends App {

  object DistanceOptions extends Enumeration {
    type Dist = Value
    val Manhattan, Eucleudian = Value
  }

  trait DistanceFunctionsType[T, A] {
    def manhattanDistance(t: (T, T)): A
    def eucleudianDistance(t: (T, T)): A
  }

  object DistanceFunctions extends DistanceFunctionsType[DataLine, Double] {

    def manhattanDistance(l1: (DataLine, DataLine)): Double = {
      val t: List[(Double, Double)] = l1._1.points.zip(l1._2.points)
      t.map(m => Math.abs(m._1 - m._2)).sum

    }

    def eucleudianDistance(l1: (DataLine, DataLine)): Double = {

      val ld: List[(Double, Double)] = l1._1.points.zip(l1._2.points)
      val sum = ld.map(m => Math.abs(m._1 - m._2) + Math.abs(m._1 - m._2)).sum

      Math.sqrt(sum)
    }

    def getDistance(distanceOptions: DistanceOptions.Dist, l1: (DataLine, DataLine)) = {

      distanceOptions match {
        case DistanceOptions.Manhattan  => DistanceFunctions.manhattanDistance(l1)
        case DistanceOptions.Eucleudian => DistanceFunctions.eucleudianDistance(l1)
      }

    }

  }

  case class DataLine(label: String, points: List[Double])
  val l = (DataLine("a", List(1, 2)), DataLine("b", List(1, 2)))

  println(DistanceFunctions.getDistance(DistanceOptions.Manhattan, l))
  println(DistanceFunctions.getDistance(DistanceOptions.Eucleudian, l))

}
```

In implementing this structure I found this guide helpful : http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes—see for example [Spire's `MetricSpace`](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spire/algebra/MetricSpace.scala), which would allow you to write something like this:

```
case class DataLine(points: List[Double])

import spire.algebra._

object manhattanDistance extends MetricSpace[DataLine, Double] {
  def distance(v: DataLine, w: DataLine): Double = {
    val ld: List[(Double, Double)] = v.points.zip(w.points)
    val sum = ld.map(m =>
      math.abs(m._1 - m._2) + math.abs(m._1 - m._2)
    ).sum

    math.sqrt(sum)
  }
}
```

This approach allows you to avoid the enumeration, and if you use Spire's implementation you get nice operators, a clean way to test that your implementation satisfies e.g. [the triangle inequality](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/scalacheck-binding/src/main/scala/spire/laws/BaseLaws.scala), and the benefit of a lot of smart people having thought about performance, specialization, etc. for you.

Comment: thanks Travis. I'd prefer to implement this myself (just to gain more exposure to Scala type system). I've updated question with potential solution using Types which appears to match your answer, although I'm not sure how to remove the Enumeration from my solution

Comment: @blue-sky I think you'll get better results if you have a trait representing a distance metric with the Euclidean and Manhattan metrics as instances. Then you can just pass in the appropriate instance (either implicitly or not) instead of passing in a separate configuration object, which just seems kind of noisy to me.